# ¿Cómo hacer un botón de búsqueda?

Tags: excel, macros

Tengo dos columnas A y B (Celda A medicamentos Celda B Resultados) y quiero buscar el contenido de la celda A y que me muestre el contenido de la celda B lo tengo de esta manera pero no me funciona.

```
Private Sub search_Click()

Dim Medicamento As String

Medicamentos = txtMedicamentos.Value

Cells.Find(What:="txtMedicamentos", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False).Activate


txtResultado.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value


End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un BUSCARV? ¿O un COINCIDIR/ÍNDICE?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub search_Click()
  Dim Medicamento As String
  Medicamentos = txtMedicamentos.Value
  Cells.Find(What:=Medicamentos, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _ SearchFormat:=False).Activate

  txtResultado.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End Sub
```